# Buddypress Language Files Question

Tags: buddypress, language

I have one question. I use latest Wordpress and Budypress. I have language files for buddypress - .po and .mo. My question is where I need to put the files, how I need to rename them and is there any function that I need to add somewhere (for example functions.php) to load them. I checked [this page](http://codex.buddypress.org/user/translations/) and try to follow the instructions, but my site is still in english.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The instructions say to put them in the `/wp-content/languages/` folder. Have you done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention for plugins translation files (`.mo` and `.po` files) is `pluginname-language_COUNTRY.mo`. So, for example, a French translation files of Buddypress will be: `buddypress-fr_FR.mo` and `buddypress-fr_FR.po`. After renaming these files, put them in `wp-content/languages` directory and your translation should work. Note that `WP_LANG` must be defined with the same language (`fr_FR` for example) for the translation files to load.